# JMS Deserialize is not retriving the object values

Tags: symfony, doctrine, jmsserializerbundle

I am using Doctrine, Symfony 2.4, the FOSRestBundle and JMSBundle to create a simple REST api.
I create a simple User entity and a controller to implement the POST method (GET method works fine). When I try to POST data my $user object properties are always null, the values on the request->data are not being deserialized.. Fighting this for the whole day really..

My User entity:

```
namespace AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Accessor;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * 
     * @Expose
     * @JMS\Type("integer")
     * @Accessor(getter="getId")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=25)
     * 
     * @Expose
     * @JMS\Type("string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUsername($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get username
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

Then in my User Controller (src/ApiBundle/Controller/UserController.php) I have:
namespace AbcBank\ApiBundle\Controller;

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\View;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;

use AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity\User;

/**
 * User controller.
 *
 * @Route("/user")
 */
class UserController extends Controller
{
    //... more code

    /**
     * POST
     * 
     * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
     * @return FormTypeInterface|View
     */
    public function postUserAction(Request $request)
    {
        $serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

        /**
         * deserialize the json content to a User type object
         */
        $content = $request->getContent();
        $user = $serializer->deserialize($content, 'AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity\User', 'json');

        if ($user instanceof \AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity\User === false) {
            return View::create(array('errors' => $user), 400);
        }

        /**
         * persist object into the database
         */
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        $url = $this->generateUrl(
            'user_get',
            array('id' => $user->getId()),
            true
        );

        $response = new Response();
        $response->setStatusCode(201);
        $response->headers->set('Location', $url);

        return $response;   
    }
}
```

Would appreciate any help.. very very frustrating and probably something silly I am missing..

kind regards.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue I think, all fields in the deserialized object are null despite having values in the JSON string

Comment: I'm having the same issue as Dai. Only my Id field is being correctly filled in, the rest is left blank. Any insight is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because the serializer converts properties from camel case to a 'lower-cased underscored name' by default and the other way round when desrializing.

Serialize:   myProperty => my_property
Desrialize:  my_property => myProperty

See the documentation for [@SerializedName](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#serializedname)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public function postUserAction(Request $request) {
$serializer = $this->get('jms_serializer');

/**
 * deserialize the json content to a User type object
 */
$content = $request->getContent();
$user = $serializer->deserialize($content, 'AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity\User', 'json');

if ($user instanceof \AbcBank\ApiBundle\Entity\User === false) {
    return View::create(array('errors' => $user), 400);
}

/**
 * persist object into the database
 */
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$updatedUser = $em->merge($user);

$em->flush();

$url = $this->generateUrl(
    'user_get',
    array('id' => $user->getId()),
    true
);

$response = new Response();
$response->setStatusCode(201);
$response->headers->set('Location', $url);

return $response };
```